# How to format a line with Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a variable in a script, lets assume it looks like this
`$x= /w =`

I want to use it in a sed expression `sed -i '/he/c\he = "'$x'"' /home/1.txt`
But for correct work it must look like this `$x='\s''/w\''\s''=\'`

So I want fist go trough the variable with sed and make the variable look correct for the next use.
But I am quite new with sed, and cant do a correct syntax.
If possible give an example based on my variable and link to read-out about such things will be good to :)

Comment: Please post sample input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this.

```
var='$x= /w ='

Tempo="$( printf "%s" "${var}" | sed 's/["\\]/\\&/g' )"

sed -i "/he/c\\
he = \"${Tempo}\"" /home/1.txt
```

Escaping some char. Just look at correct simple and double quote between escaping  and your sed that need a double quote.